# Select a html button in applescript

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, applescript, automator

I'm writing a program that I want to be able to open safari and select a button based on it's ID. I'm pretty new to Applescript, and have an error I cannot solve. I could use some help.

Error: Expected “end” but found “to”.

```
on run {input, parameters}

to clickID(theId)
tell application “Safari”
do JavaScript “document.getElementById(‘” & theId & “‘).click();” in document 1
end tell
end clickID

clickID(“htb_more“)

return input
end run
```

Again, this might be pretty obvious o somebody. If you need any elaboration, just ask. I did not think there was much to this program and thought I would be able to write it easily, but I got stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood some of the structure of Applescript. I believe what you're looking for is more like the code below.

```
on run
    clickID("htb_more")
end run

on clickID(theId)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById(‘” & theId & “‘).click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickID
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. However, it did not solve my problem. I added my full problem on another page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589438/learning-applescript-trouble-linking-to-safari     - Also, if could maybe point me in the direction of some Applescript learning sources, that would be helpful :)